# Two TextViews always on Screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to place two TextViews side by side such that both are always on the screen.

They should always stay next to each other, touching borders. But the text keeps changing dynamically, so even if the text in the first TV becomes too long, it should not push the second TV off the screen.

Here's the basic layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Aa" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Bb" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Basic Layout]

However, if the text becomes long, the second TextView gets pushed off the screen.

[image: Second TV pushed off screen]

I even tried the same thing using RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/a"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Bb" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Still the same problem, the second TextView just won't stay on the screen. I want the first textView to get ellipsized, or convert into two lines without pushing the second TextView off the screen. But I also don't want the second TextView to be stuck to the right of the screen (this can be done by giving the first TextView a weight of 1)

PS: For me, the background of the Views is immaterial, so even if I can manage this by latching the view onto the right side of the screen, it's perfectly fine.
For this, I've tried using **weights** on both views in *LinearLayout*, and **layout_alignParentRight** in *RelativeLayout* - but without any success.

Edit:

If i use weights on both layouts - this is what it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Aaa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Bbfbd" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Weights on both Views]

This is fine if the text is long, but with short text, it defeats the purpose.

With long text it works perfectly.
[image: Weight with long text]

**Solution:**

The only solution I could figure out was to define the maxWidth property for the first TextView. This property is defined in dimens.xml, with a different value for different screen sizes.

> main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxWidth="@dimen/max_text_view_width"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Bbbbbbb" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="max_text_view_width">300dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

The Output for this looks like this:
[image: Output with maxWidth]

Comment: What is the problem you facing while using weight ?

Comment: What if your long text contain space? Ex: aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa

Comment: @JagjitSingh if I use weights on the first TextView, the second TextView is stuck to the right edge of the screen. I want the first TextView to only take as much space as it's text requires. If however, I apply weights to the second TextView, it still gets pushed off the screen if the text is too long in the first TextView.

Comment: @Rachit then please try using maxWidth and and toRightOf  attribute. Hope it will help

Comment: Hey @Rachit try to use this PercentRelative layout of google https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

Comment: @JagjitSingh, could you please share code for your solution?

Comment: @Rachit look at my new answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked for me was to set the maxWidth for the first View.

I set the maxWidth in the dimens xml and overridded the value for multiple screen sizes. It was difficult testing it out on multiple screens, but that's what finally worked for me.

```
android:maxWidth="@dimen/max_width"
```

Answer (score 3):

> `TextView` has a property of `maxWidth` . you can set that
>   programmatically

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;  //width of the screen
        int height = size.y; // height of the screen
        textView1.setMaxWidth(width/2);
        textView2.setMaxWidth(width/2); //disable this if you want to have the rest of the screen by second textView
```

> Now, textView will initially have the minimum size and will grow to
>   the maximum of the half size of the screen. You can customize this
>   with condition to fullfill your needs.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I guess this is the only solution here. I'm gonna do this using xml's though.. I'll set a maxWidth property to the view using dimens resource, and specify different widths for different device sizes.

Comment: yes you can do it by xml but that may introduce problems in lower resolution or higher ones as you never know what's the size of the user's screen. better go with dynamic settings.

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok for the textviews to be static you can leave them in LinearLayout and assign weight=1 to each of them. That way they are always going to stay the same.

For a much better and flexible solution use Google's [flexbox layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout). It is an awesome library where you can do all kinds of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[image]This will definately works :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Asssda" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/a"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Bxdadsdc" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: With this, if the text is small on both view, they are split equally on the screen. I don't want that.. I want the view to look like the first image in the question.

Comment: What you actuallt want? Can you share output design?

Comment: Use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout as i have done in above answer.

Comment: @ZaptechDevKumar I don't want the space between the two TextViews.. The first TextView should only take up as much space as it needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="wqkdnoqwndowqndowqowndowqndodnwqodnqow" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Aaaaaaaaainqwdiwdiwdniwqndiwqiwndiwqndiwqdniqwnnwiqdwoqndqowqndolnqwdlnaa\nkpaaaa" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Its not exaclty the solution but you should use this approach of using weights in linear layouts.

Comment: Please see my edit above. This doesn't work with small text. Only when the text is long.

Answer (score 0):

**Enter the below code and the problem will be solved:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:maxLines="2000"
        android:text="Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/a"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please see my edit above. This only works with long text, doesn't work if I make the text small.

Answer (score 0):

What could work is setting the maxWidth for the first View. You could set the maxWidth using xml resources for multiple screen sizes.

```
android:maxWidth="@dimen/max_width"
```

Then you could set `max_width` in dimens.xml

Answer (score 0):

Giving each view an equal weight would make them occupy half the screen. That is not what you're looking for, I guess.

I think the best option here is to programmatically calculate the screen width of the device and set the max width of the first textView as a percentage of the screen width.